# errors in virtual functions code

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
const double PI=3.14;
class shape
{
public:
    virtual void print()=0;
    virtual float area()=0;
};
class twodimensional:public shape
{
public:
    virtual float perimeter()=0;
};
class threedimensional:public shape
{
public:
    virtual float volume()=0;
};
class circle:public twodimensional
{
private:
    float raduis;
public:
    circle(float r):raduis(r)
    {}
    void print()
    {
        cout<<"shape is a circle\n";
        cout<<"circle raduis="<<raduis<<endl;
    }
    float perimeter()
    { return 2*PI*raduis;}
    float area()
    { return PI*raduis*raduis;}
};
class cone:public threedimensional
{
private:
    float raduis,height;
public:
    cone(float r,float h)
    {
        r=raduis;h=height;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout<<"Shaps is a cone"<<endl;
        cout<<"cone's raduis="<<raduis<<",height="<<height<<endl;
    }
    float area
    {
        float s=sqrt(raduis*raduis+height*height);
        return PI*raduis*(raduis+s);
    }
    float volume
    {
        return PI*raduis*raduis*height/3;
    }
};
int main()
{
    circle x(12.5f);
    x.print();
    cout<<"the perimeter of the circle="<<x.perimeter()<<endl;
    cout<<"the area of the circle="<<x.area<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cone y(4.3f,8.2f);
    y.print();
    cout<<"The volume of the circle ="<<y.volume()<<endl;
    cout<<"The area of the circle ="<<y.area()<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

i got so much errors while trying debugging this code about polymorphism and virtual function , so if anyone can help me !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!i got so much errors while trying debugging this code about polymorphism and virtual function , so if anyone can help me !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Your class has no constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you method definition is not proper in `Cone` class. You are missing the `()` in the `area` and `volume` definition. Please modify as follows;

```
float area()
{
    float s=sqrt(raduis*raduis+height*height);
    return PI*raduis*(raduis+s);
}
float volume()
{
    return PI*raduis*raduis*height/3;
}
```

also you need to change the method call in your `main()` method.

```
cout<<"the area of the circle="<<x.area<<endl;
```

Here also you are not using `()` in `x.area`. Modify as follows.

```
cout<<"the area of the circle="<<x.area()<<endl;
```

Hope this helps.